# Align navbar toggle button to the right

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar, bootstrap-4

I'm having a play around with Bootstrap 4, more specifically the navbar menu. Is there is a way I can make the little navbar toggle button align to the right of the page rather than have it floating to the left next to the logo?

[image]

This is my current code.

```css
@media (min-width: 992px) {
    .navbar-nav li a { line-height: 85px; }
}

@media (max-width: 991px) {
    .navbar-brand { float: none; }
}

.navbar-toggler{
    border:none;
    width:1em;
}
```

```html
 <nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-faded navbar-full">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img class="img-fluid" src="img/logoMedium.png" /></a>
          <button class="navbar-toggler hidden-lg-up" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation"></button>
          <div class="collapse navbar-toggleable-md" id="navbarResponsive">
              <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                  <li class="nav-item active">
                      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item">
                      <a class="nav-link" href="#">About Us</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item">
                      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Solar Power</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item">
                      <a class="nav-link" href="#">No Obligation Quote</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item">
                      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact Us</a>
                  </li>
              </ul>
          </div>
      </nav>
```

Thanks for the help :)

Comment: "navbar-toggler-right" class on your button to toggle can help you for this.

Answer (score 28):

just add the class `ml-auto` to your toggle button
in that way you make margin-left:auto

```
<button type="button" class="navbar-toggler ml-auto hidden-sm-up float-xs-right" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation"></button>
```

Comment: For Bootstrap 5 and above, use `ms-auto` instead of `ml-auto`

Answer (score 3):

Use `.float-xs-right` class:

```
<button class="navbar-toggler hidden-lg-up float-xs-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation"></button>
```

Or add `float: right;` to `.navbar-toggler` as the below snippet:

[Note that pull-right has been removed in v4.](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/migration/#utilities)

```css
@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .navbar-nav li a {
    line-height: 85px;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 991px) {
  .navbar-brand {
    float: none;
  }
}
.navbar-toggler {
  border: none;
  width: 1em;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-faded navbar-full">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
    <img class="img-fluid" src="img/logoMedium.png" />
  </a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler hidden-lg-up" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation"></button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-toggleable-md" id="navbarResponsive">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">About Us</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Solar Power</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">No Obligation Quote</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact Us</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

Put the class **pull-right** and you'll get the result that you're looking for.

```
<button class="navbar-toggler hidden-lg-up pull-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation"></button>
```

or you can define a style with the following parameters:

```
float: right !important;
```

Comment: Could you please be more specific about which tag I should add it too, because I have tried the pull-right tag with no luck.

Comment: Please, take a look.

Comment: Thanks for the help Dan, however I have tried it and its done nothing.

Comment: .pull-right and .pull-left have been removed from Bootstrap 4: https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/migration/#utilities

Answer (score 1):

try this piece of code:

```
    .navbar-toggler {  
  margin-left: 90% !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In bootstrap 5 you can just do this :
add the class 'ms-auto' and your toggler will shift from left to right

```
<button class="navbar-toggler ms-auto" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
  <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
</button>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solved this:

```
<header>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-dark bg-inverse">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Fixed top</a>
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggler hidden-sm-up float-xs-right" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation"></button>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-toggleable-xs" id="navbarResponsive">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="nav-item active">
                    <a href="#" class="nav-link">Home<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="#" class="nav-link">Planets</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="" class="nav-link">Spaceships</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="" class="nav-link">About</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="" class="nav-link">Contact</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
</header>
```

Note that you have to use the clearfix, because otherwise the float from the button would do funky things to the menu while it's collapsing.

Answer (score 0):

This is what works for me in Bootstrap 4

```
<button type="button" class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right"
        data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse"
        aria-controls="navbar-collapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
```

or even simpler from [Bootstrap docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/)

```
<button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
<span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
 .navbar-light .navbar-nav .nav-link {
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255) !important;
}
.navbar {
    
    display: block !important;
        min-height: 54px;
    }
    .pull-right{
    float:right !important;
    }
```

```html
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Popper JS -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
       <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light" style="background-color: #de7a22 !important;">
           
            <button class="navbar-toggler pull-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar" aria-controls="myNavbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>

            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
                <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                    <li class="nav-item active">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#"><i class="fa fa-home"></i><span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Gallery</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Services</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Sponsorship</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact us</a></li>
                  
                </ul>

            </div>

        </nav>
        </body>
```

Comment: Some explanation of your solution would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You have to align it just like another button tag, first wrap it inside a container to be able to move it later, after that create a div with .text-right class and then put your toggle button inside. See the example below.

```
<div class='container'>
   <div class='text-right'>
      <button> Button1 </button>
   </div>    
</div>
```

or

```
<div class='container text-right'>       
   <button> Button1 </button>       
</div>enter code here
```

Both solutions work perfectly in Bootstrap 4.5

Answer (score 0):

Just use `navbar-expand-lg` and your problem will going to solve.

It should look like this:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light fixed-top">
```

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get any of the above solutions to work.  So this simple hack does the job:

**HTML**:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light sticky-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row d-inline">
      <div class="col">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="{% url 'home' %}">
          <img src="{% static  'img/logo.png' %}" alt="Logo" height="100" class="d-inline-block">
          <span class="fs-2">Abstract Spacecraft</span>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="col">
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" 
          aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation" id="as-navbar-toggler">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
```

**CSS**:

```
#as-navbar-toggler {
    position: absolute;
    right: 5px;
    top: 5px;
    height: 35px;
    padding: 0px;
}
```

**Result (in Chrome's iPhone5 screen emulator):**
[image]

What's nice about this is because there's 0 padding, it rides nicely over the default (centered) page title.

Comment: I think if the logo were small, the navbar toggle button would collide with the title.  I'm really a bootstrap newbie, and am looking for any suggestions on my code, as well.