# Bootstrap 4 Alpha 6 navbar-toggler-right and left create strange behavior

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-4

I have a simple navbar:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-toggleable-md fixed-top custom-navbar" style="background-color: #321048;">
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
            <ul class="navbar-nav d-flex justify-content-end" style="width:100%">
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#home">Home</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#rolfing">Rolfing</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#packages">Packages</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#about">About</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#footer">Contact</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
</nav>
```

And everything works as expected for all screen sizes. 
[image]
I wanted to right justify the toggler because the menu is right justified. So per Bootstrap 4 alpha 6, I added

```
navbar-toggler-right
```

to the button, and it indeed does right justify the button, but the navbar itself no longer expands to fill the button. So the toggle button looks to be just floating. I am content to leave navbar-toggler-right out let it work, but I am just curious why it would do that. something to do with navbar-toggler-right having an absolute position perhaps. navbar-toggler-left does the same thing as well.

[image]

**EDIT**
To offer more detail, it does not matter that the toggle button be on the left or on the right. Adding the class navbar-toggler-left causes the same problem. My question is not how to move the toggle button to the right (I can do that by adding float:right to the button), but why the 
navbar-toggler-left and right classes have that strange behavior.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bootstrap 4 -- Align navbar toggle button to the right](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41153123/bootstrap-4-align-navbar-toggle-button-to-the-right)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an open issue for this:

https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/21846

A workaround is to use a placeholder instead of the `navbar-brand`

`<span class="navbar-text">&nbsp;</span>`

Comment: There's been a year and this issue is still there.

Answer (score 13):

No offense but you should only add `.ml-auto`, that works.

Comment: This should be the taken answer. No issue nothing. This works.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Both the brand name and the toggler were left aligned. I solved the problem with `<ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto  ">`. It worked.

So, you may try `<ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto  ">`
 instead of  `ul class="navbar-nav d-flex justify-content-end" style="width:100%"`

Answer (score -2):

You can try using `navbar-toggle` instead of `navbar-toggler`. It might help but in your situation, but not certain.

Comment: in older verion of css you have navbar-toggle class which goes like this .navbar-toggle {
  position: relative;
  float: right;
  padding: 9px 10px;
  margin-top: 8px;
  margin-right: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
  background-color: transparent;
  background-image: none;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 4px;
} in newer verion of css you have navbar-toggler class which is different and leads your button to be somewhere in the middle of the page